# rails command not working for Jruby 1.6.2 rails 3.0.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jruby

I am trying to create new rails project. I have installed rails 3.0.9 for Jruby platform-1.6.2.

I get following error.

"
'"jruby.bat.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
"

Please do the needful, thanks for your time.

Thanks and Regards,
Sachin Jadhav.

Answer (score 0):

What command are you running? It looks like the rails.bat stub might have been generated incorrectly. Try running with `jruby.exe -S rails` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Done!

I changed all bat files in bin... there it has been specified like *.bat.exe...
I renamed it to *.exe.

Wish you luck!
Sachin Jadhav

Answer (score 0):

I also got this problem and this was because of jruby.bat.exe name written in your rails.bat file in rails 3.0.9 bin folder. Please go and rename to jruby.exe, it will work fine.